# How do you disable html preview in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, preview, disable

[image]

Please help me get rid of the panel I can not edit my html. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

More than likely this is not native vscode functionality. Check one of your plugins and uninstall it.

Comment: Right! .. Visual Studio Code do not support preview HTML Files So as you said it not native Visual Studio Code functionality .. It is from one of  Extensions that you installed

Comment: Accept your Answer as the correct answer .. Good Luck :)